# I am getting an error and the screen is rendering as blank. What should I do?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, frontend

This the error I am getting:- react.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at ProductEditScreen.js:135.

I wasn't getting the error before, until I added "multer" package.
I am making this project with help of a course. The guy added the package and changed the same code, I did the same but am getting a blank screen. This his [code](https://github.com/bradtraversy/proshop_mern/commit/4f3a94f5f2f049fd2a7506ba6207ba25df8cee8f). These are my files [uploadRoutes.js](https://github.com/niruparekh09/shopee-website/blob/main/backend/routes/uploadRoutes.js) [server.js](https://github.com/niruparekh09/shopee-website/blob/main/backend/server.js) [ProductEditScreen.js](https://github.com/niruparekh09/shopee-website/blob/main/frontend/src/screens/ProductEditScreen.js).
Please help me with this problem, I have been scratching my head for hours.
The problem is in ProductEditScreen.js